# Tf-idf vectorizer has whitespaces in feature words with char_wb?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I use

```
singleTFIDF = TfidfVectorizer(
    analyzer='char_wb', 
    ngram_range=(4,6),
    stop_words=my_stop_words, 
    max_features=50
).fit([text])
```

And wonder why there are whitespaces in my features like 'chaft '

How can I avoid this? Do I need to tokenize and preprocess this myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `analyzer='word'`.

When we use **`analyzer='char_wb'`, vectorizer pads the white space** because it won't tokenize with respect to words; it tokenizes with respect to characters.

According to [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) for the `analyzer` argument:

> `analyzer{‘word’, ‘char’, ‘char_wb’} or callable, default=’word’`
>
> Whether the feature should be made of word or character n-grams. **Option ‘char_wb’ creates character n-grams** only from text **inside word boundaries**; n-grams at the **edges of words are padded with space**.

Look at the following example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(
  analyzer='char_wb', 
  ngram_range= (4,6))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print([(len(w),w) for w in vectorizer.get_feature_names()])
```

> [(4, ' and'), (5, ' and '), (4, ' doc'), (5, ' docu'), (6, ' docum'),
> (4, ' fir'), (5, ' firs'), (6, ' first'), (4, ' is '), (4, ' one'),
> (5, ' one.'), (6, ' one. '), (4, ' sec'), (5, ' seco'), (6, ' secon'),
> (4, ' the'), (5, ' the '), (4, ' thi'), (5, ' thir'), (6, ' third'),
> (5, ' this'), (6, ' this '), (4, 'and '), (4, 'cond'), (5, 'cond '),
> (4, 'cume'), (5, 'cumen'), (6, 'cument'), (4, 'docu'), (5, 'docum'),
> (6, 'docume'), (4, 'econ'), (5, 'econd'), (6, 'econd '), (4, 'ent '),
> (4, 'ent.'), (5, 'ent. '), (4, 'ent?'), (5, 'ent? '), (4, 'firs'), (5,
> 'first'), (6, 'first '), (4, 'hird'), (5, 'hird '), (4, 'his '), (4,
> 'ird '), (4, 'irst'), (5, 'irst '), (4, 'ment'), (5, 'ment '), (5,
> 'ment.'), (6, 'ment. '), (5, 'ment?'), (6, 'ment? '), (4, 'ne. '), (4,
> 'nt. '), (4, 'nt? '), (4, 'ocum'), (5, 'ocume'), (6, 'ocumen'), (4,
> 'ond '), (4, 'one.'), (5, 'one. '), (4, 'rst '), (4, 'seco'), (5,
> 'secon'), (6, 'second'), (4, 'the '), (4, 'thir'), (5, 'third'), (6,
> 'third '), (4, 'this'), (5, 'this '), (4, 'umen'), (5, 'ument'), (6,
> 'ument '), (6, 'ument.'), (6, 'ument?')]

Notice:

- the output/features **include `' this'`** (padded at the start by an extra space that is not there in the original text; the sentence starts with `'This'`)
- the output/features **include `'ment. '`** (padded at the end by an extra space that is not there in the original text; the sentence ends with `'document.'`)
- the output/features **do not** include `'is the'`, because that n-gram crosses a word boundary, but the `'char_wb'` analyzer only creates n-grams "**inside word boundaries**"

Comment: Isee. But i want to use ngrams. I also don't know how the defaults for preprocessing like tokenization is for analyzer=char? I get also punctuation. Can I use a custom preprocessing with analyzer=char_wb?

Comment: I see. wouldn't it be tough for models to learn from char encoding? Can you add some context of the usage, in your question. we can still use the ngrams with word tokenizing. Ofcourse we can customize preprocessor and then use char_wb for tokenization

Comment: If we remove the space, it would loose the word ending. Good approach could be just remove the punctuations.

Comment: Thanks. I feel using ngrams you need to preprocess most on your won while with 'word' most of the things is done by default. What would be the right way to preprocess and usng char_wb afterwards? Shall I do this with a custom tokenizer or  within a custom preprocessing? I want to do stemming and need to remove the stop words by my own as with char_wb they are not removed by default!

Comment: Ok. But I think you can increase results when removing those "duplicates" with whitespace? Also, using ngrams(4,6) gets you a lot of similiar tokens like:[' inl', ' inla', ' inlan', ' vor', 'aft ', 'anwa', 'eis ', 'haft', 'haft ', 'inla', 'inlan', 'inland', 'land', 'nlan', 'nland', 'nwar', 'reis', 'reis ', 'rtsc', 'schaf']

Comment: Any comments @AI_Learning ?

Comment: Those are still different features according to the char ngram logic, since `haft` could a sub word and `haft ` could be a complete word