# Eliminate unigrams in char-level TF-IDF

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, tf-idf

I would like to extract unique combinations of letters within words using the scikit-learn TF-IDF vectorizer for an NLP problem. However, I'm not interested in individual letters, but letter combinations, so that, e.g. "the" should produce "th" and "he" but not "t", "h" or "e". My understanding is I should be able to use `ngram_range`. However, using `ngram_range=(2,3)` is still returning unigrams.

Example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

examples = ['The cat on the mat',
            'Fast and bulbous']

tfidf =  TfidfVectorizer(max_features=None, 
                         analyzer='char_wb',
                         ngram_range=(2, 3))

data=tfidf.fit_transform(examples)

print(pd.DataFrame(data=data.todense(),
             index=examples,
             columns = tfidf.get_feature_names_out()))
```

gives me the 2- and 3-gram results as expected but also unigrams (i.e. I don't want "a", "b", etc.):

```
                           a        an         b        bu         c  \
The cat on the mat  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.139994   
Fast and bulbous    0.181053  0.181053  0.181053  0.181053  0.000000   

                          ca         f        fa         m        ma  ...  \
The cat on the mat  0.139994  0.000000  0.000000  0.139994  0.139994  ...   
Fast and bulbous    0.000000  0.181053  0.181053  0.000000  0.000000  ...   

                          s         st       st         t         th  \
The cat on the mat  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.199213  0.279987   
Fast and bulbous    0.181053  0.181053  0.181053  0.128821  0.000000   

                         the        ul       ulb        us       us   
The cat on the mat  0.279987  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  
Fast and bulbous    0.000000  0.181053  0.181053  0.181053  0.181053  

[2 rows x 53 columns]
```

I would've expected this output with `ngram_range=(1,3)` but not `ngram_range=(2,3)`.

---

**Edit:**
I just noticed that "a" is extracted from "Fast and bulbous", presumably as it occurs as " a", i.e. with a space before the "a", but not in "The cat on the mat" as the "a" in "cat" is surrounded by "c" and "t". Likewise, "u" is not extracted as there is no space surrounding it in either text.

It seems like `TfidfVectorizer` is extracting bigrams including spaces. Is there a way to turn this off? (I though using `analyzer='char_wb'` searched within words rather than across words).

Comment: Relevant previous discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308898/tf-idf-vectorizer-has-whitespaces-in-feature-words-with-char-wb

Answer (score 0):

I constructed a callable to pass to `analyzer`. It is <s>stolen from</s> based on the function from the [source code of TfidfVectorizer](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3f51f9b6/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py) used when analyzer is set to 'char_wb':

```
def char_wb_ngrams(text_document, ngram_range):
    """Callable for TfidfVectorizer analyzer, based on _char_wb_ngrams from TfidfVectorizer source code at
    https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3f51f9b6/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py"""

    ngrams = []
    min_n, max_n = ngram_range

    for w in text_document.lower().split():
        # This line in _char_wb_ngrams pads words with spaces and needs to be removed:
        #w = " " + w + " "
        w_len = len(w)
        for n in range(min_n, max_n + 1):
            offset = 0
            ngrams.append(w[offset : offset + n])
            while offset + n < w_len:
                offset += 1
                ngrams.append(w[offset : offset + n])
            if offset == 0:  # count a short word (w_len < n) only once
                break
    return ngrams
```

This works on the example data from above:

```
from functools import partial

tfidf_no_space =  TfidfVectorizer(max_features=None, 
                                  analyzer=partial(char_wb_ngrams, ngram_range=(2,3)),
                                  ngram_range=(2, 3))

data=tfidf_no_space.fit_transform(examples)

print(pd.DataFrame(data=data.todense(),
             index=examples,
             columns = tfidf_no_space.get_feature_names_out()))
```

which yields

```
                          an       and        as       ast        at  \
The cat on the mat  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.436436   
Fast and bulbous    0.229416  0.229416  0.229416  0.229416  0.000000   

                          bo       bou        bu       bul        ca  ...  \
The cat on the mat  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.218218  ...   
Fast and bulbous    0.229416  0.229416  0.229416  0.229416  0.000000  ...   

                          nd        on        ou       ous        st  \
The cat on the mat  0.000000  0.218218  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   
Fast and bulbous    0.229416  0.000000  0.229416  0.229416  0.229416   

                          th       the        ul       ulb        us  
The cat on the mat  0.436436  0.436436  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  
Fast and bulbous    0.000000  0.000000  0.229416  0.229416  0.229416  

[2 rows x 28 columns]
```

I'm not sure this would work with punctuation, though. It would be good to have a version that strips punctuation and also doesn't require the call to `partial` (which fixes `ngram_range` in the function).